# Is there any equivalent feature in AWS to Azure AD B2B?

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, azure-ad-b2c, aws-userpools, azure-ad-b2b

I understand that Azure AD B2C has an equivalent in AWS, which is AWS Cognito User Pool.

But it seems there is nothing equivalent to the Azure AD B2B. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

With **Azure AD B2B**, the partner uses their own identity management solution, so there is no external administrative overhead for your organization

Guest users sign-in to your apps and services with their own work, school, or social identities

**There is no equivalent feature in AWS to Azure AD B2B**